# Advanced Personalization in SharePoint (User Preferences, Web Part drag and drop)

Tags: wss-3.0, ajax, silverlight, 2007

I need some pointers / thoughts on how to achieve this advanced personalization in SharePoint with User Preference, profiles, favorites, etc.

I see a product is already on the market so it's technically possible; But I would like to know how (AJAX, silverlight, custom chrome, profile store, etc.)

How did they achieve this?

http://www.handshakesoftware.com/Products/PageGuru/tabid/96/Default.aspx. (broken URL).

Any pointers or thoughts appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: On the assumption that your question is genuine, we'll leave it, but if you are trying to plug the Handshake product, please don't do it on SPOverflow.

Comment: @anderson : I am not trying to plugin the product, I am more curious on how this can be implemented/done..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using JavaScript or Silverlight (which this looks like) and then just use the (SPLimited)WebPartManager to edit the page.

Answer (score 0):

At some point I was planning to do the same thing .. using the webpart manager on the page , and some pop asp.net (using ajax toolkit and ajax extender) to drag and drop on it .. and then when the user hits save I rearrange the webparts on the page accordingally..
My initial thought on what http://www.handshakesoftware.com/Products/PageGuru/tabid/96/Default.aspx
is doing is that they are using 
this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/MakingGoogleIG.aspx, regular asp.net application page with ajax and silver light as Wictor mrntioned , totally by bypassing the webpart frame work to gadgets and widgets ...
I will schedul a demo with them soon .. we are looking into purchase may be

Comment: Sorry guys I am not trying to plug the handshake too ,my comment might seam like it .... never know of it will meet every bodies need any way .. connecting to database end .. and so